# Geocoding API which provides city/region/country/etc details with a single request/response

Tags: api, geography, geocoding

I am trying to find an API or a data source which provides complex geolocation and place informations.

My request : "City district name"

API respond :

- City district data (name + id + gps ...)
- City data (name + id + gps
  ...)
- Region data (name + id + gps ...)
- Country data (name + id + gps
  ...)
- Continent data (name + id + gps ...)

Problem is, that I need this data in **one** API respond. Ideal would be multilingual API.

I know there is Google with its APIs, but in Google API respond there is just data about requested item. If I request some city name, I need to do next requests to get region data, country data etc.

Do you know a way how to get that kind of data ? I am open to API, or database source or whatever.

Thank you.